# Ignoring CSS from parent style in styled-component React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am creating a React component using an existing component library that uses styled component. I time to time need to override the style from the parent library and use my own. Here is a TextInput component from the library that has style,

```
border: 2px solid black;
```

while using this component I don't want to have the border around the input box. Instead, I just want one underline.

I did it two ways,
**Using style props**,

```
<TextInput
name="test-input"
value={testInput}
onChange={onInputChange}
style={{borderTop: 'none',borderRight: 'none',
borderLeft:'none', borderBottom: '2px solid black'}}
/>
```

By this I get a black border-bottom but it requires me to repeat for all other three. Is there a better way so that I can write one line and that solves my issue ?

**I created a styled component based on the existing component,**

```
const TextInputStyled = styled(TextInput)`
border-top: none;
border-right: none;
border-left: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black`;
```

And here my component with the above style.

```
<TextInputStyled
                name="test-input"
                value={testInput}
                onChange={onInputChange}
            />
```

In this case I get the border-bottom with 2px black but the other border also exist and this is also a repetition.

Is there a better to do this ?  I often need to twitch the style of the parent component.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this code:

```
<TextInput
name="test-input"
value={testInput}
onChange={onInputChange}
style={{border:'unset', borderBottom: '2px solid black'}}
/>
```

Update:

If you insist on using styled component, ThemeProvider is the solution:

```
const TextInput=styled.input `
border: 2px solid black;
border-bottom:  ${props => props.theme.borderBottom};
border-top:${props => props.theme.borderTop};
border-left:${props => props.theme.borderLeft};
border-right:${props => props.theme.borderRight};
`;

       \\Define what props.theme will look like
 const theme= {
    borderTop: 'none;',
    borderRight: 'none;',
    borderLeft: 'none;',
    borderBottom: '1px solid black;'
  }
return(<>
  \\normal TextInput with border
 <TextInput
name="test-input"
/>


     \\customized TextInput without border except underline
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <TextInput
name="test-input"



/>
</ThemeProvider>
</>
)
```

If you don't know about ThemeProvider read this article:

https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced

Comment: Hello @bami, thank you. this works but I've multiple fields and also there is on-hover effect. So, I wanted to go with Styled component way that is changing the parent style from a separate file for all the fields than using "style" property for each field.

Comment: @sandy Check the edited answer please